# How to convert read-while loop into select menu

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following read-while loop in my Bash script that works to take a number between 1-4 as options from the user, and carries on with a warning and a "default" option if invalid. However, I've recently come across the `select` built-in and feel that converting my read-while loop into one could simplify my script a good deal. The problem is I'm not sure how to use `read -n1` in combination with `select`, so that the first `1` character of user input is automatically processed without pressing enter.

What's the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

I'm also aware that there are other redundancies in the loop that I haven't been able to fix, so I'd welcome any improvements or optimisations on that front.

```
     wmstream1="[2:v]lut=a=val*0.7,fade=in:st=5:d=2:alpha=1,fade=out:st=$length1:d=2:alpha=1[v2];"
     wmstream2="[v2][tmp2]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih*0.1[wm_scaled][video];"
     read -n1 -p "Select watermark position:
1) Top right
2) Top left
3) Bottom left
4) None
" ans  
    while true; do 
    case $ans in
    1)  echo
        echo "WARNING: defaulting to top-right position."
        wmstream3="[video][wm_scaled]overlay=$wmpos:format=auto:shortest=1[outv];"
        break               
        ;;
    2)  echo
        echo "Positioning watermark at top left."
        wmpos="50:50"
        wmstream3="[video][wm_scaled]overlay=$wmpos:format=auto:shortest=1[outv];"
        break
        ;;
    3)  echo
        echo "Positioning watermark at bottom left."
        wmpos="50:H-h-50"
        wmstream3="[video][wm_scaled]overlay=$wmpos:format=auto:shortest=1[outv];"
        break
        ;;
    4)  echo
        echo "Disabling watermark."
        unset wmstream1
        unset wmstream2
        wmstream3="[tmp2]setsar=1[outv];"
        break
        ;;
    *)  echo 
        echo "Invalid option selected. Select a valid number."
        break
        ;;
    esac
    done
```

Comment: Btw.: You use `break` in every case. That means you can remove your `while` loop and every `break` from your code.

Comment: Btw.: Every case starts with `echo`. You can remove that and insert it once before your `case` command in a separate line.

Comment: @Cyrus The `break` in the catch-all case is likely incorrect. However, you could put `continue` in that case and put a single `break` *after* the `case` statement, rather than repeating `break` in each valid-response case.

Answer (score 1):

select would be a replacement for while loop in your case:

```
...
select ans in "Top Right" "Top Left" "Bottom Left" None
do
  case $ans in
    "Top Right") <Your code here>
    "Top Left")  <your code here>
    "Bottom Left") <Your code here>
    None) <your code here>
esac
done
```

you don't have to use so many echoes as pointed out by @Cyrus in the comment.
You can put a single echo right before
the case block  after the select statement.

Also, while loop was not really necessary in the first place in your code (if that's all it is) since you are only prompting the  user for just one input and that too, only once.

EDIT:
elect takes user input so that would be a replacement for read as well. Unless you want to use both together to take two inputs (which is not apparent in the code ), select here would replace read i.e. if you want to use select.

Comment: This doesn't address the primary problem of how to use `read -n1` in combination with `select`, as I'm currently doing with the while-read loop.

Comment: @HashimAziz select takes user input so that would be a replacement for ```read``` as well. Unless you want to use both together to take two inputs (which is not apparent in the code ), select here would replace ```read```. I think i should add that to my answer

Comment: The key for me is read's `-n1` feature - if that can't be emulated using `select` I'll probably have to stick to `while-read`.

Comment: Right. The `select` built-in waits the user to press the enter key and cannot emulate `read -n1`.

Comment: @tshiono Thanks for the confirmation.